# How to listing multiple database on one gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have multiple database table. I want to show them in one devexpress gridview.

I used this codes below and its works.

First question is that true ? 
Second question is that, can i show the table name on another column which name is Categori?

```
private void Firma_Std_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Categori");
    dt.Columns.Add("Code");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    baglanti.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select cade, name  from TSE union all select kod,ad from ISO union all select kod,ad from TURKAK;", baglanti);
    da.Fill(dt);
    baglanti.Close();
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;        
}
```

Comment: for first question it can be one way but it doesnt best way, second question you can use alias for colum in t-sql for example:  Select name as CategoryName from category

Comment: Would you suggest me a better way to do it ?